# C++ Why is the converter constructor implicitly called?

Tags: c++

Why is the Child class's converter constructor called in the code below?

I mean, it automatically converts Base to Child via the Child converter constructor. The code below compiles, but shouldn't it *not* compile since I haven't provided `bool Child::operator!=(Base const&)`?

```
class Base
{
};

class Child : public Base
{
public:
  Child() {}
  Child(Base const& base_) :
    Base(base_)
  {
    std::cout <<"should never called!";
  }
  bool operator!=(Child const&)
  {
    return true;
  }
};

void main()
{
  Base  base;
  Child child;

  if(child != base)
    std::cout << "not equal";
  else
    std::cout << "equal";
}
```

Comment: I guess this post could be a good use case of why the explicit keyword exists.

Comment: Should I rename the title from copy constructor to converter constructor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you provided a conversion constructor. If you don't want the compiler to automatically convert `Base` objects to `Child` using the

```
Child(Base const& base_)
```

constructor, make it explicit:

```
explicit Child(Base const& base_)
```

This way, the constructor will only be called when you explicitly specify it, in contexts like:

```
Child ch(base);
foo(Child(base));
new Child(base);
```

Comment: Thank you. Now I understand the needs for explicit keyword.

Answer (score 6):

The function with the signature `Child(Base const& base_)` is not a copy constructor (the right hand side type is not the same as the left's). That constructor can be used implicitly by the compiler to coerce one type into another for the purpose of the comparison you are making in `main`. To prevent this mark the constructor `explicit`.

Answer (score 1):

Because Child cannot be compared to Base - it can only be compared to another Child. Thus, your compiler creates an implicit copy of Base to Child in order to cause the conversion. If you change your code to:

```
class Child : public Base
{
public:
  Child() {}
  explicit Child(Base const& base_) :
    Base(base_)
  {
    std::cout <<"should never called!";
  }
  bool operator!=(Child const&)
  {
    return true;
  }
};
```

You'll find that it no longer compiles.

Answer (score 0):

Because you don't provide any operator!=() that take Base as argument : the compiler will try "what he can" and see that there is a conversion constructor to the argument type (Child) that can be called. So it use it to make the != work.